# How can I customize the main splash screen with animation in an Angular NativeScript Android application?

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I would like to customize the splash screen with some animation in my Angular NativeScript Android application. I don't want to simply add an activity before, because I want it to occur while the framework is actually loading. Can this be achieved by extending the NativeScriptApplication or Activity? If so, could I get a pointer on where to find the splash screen implementation for overriding? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that the splash screen is not meant (by guidelines form both Android and iOS) to create an interactive environment. Its main purpose is to provide content while the application is loading/bootstrapping. That said, there should be no need to extend the NativeScript Activity in order to create your own custom splash screen.

Here is [the documentation article](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/creating-launch-screens-android) that could guide you on how you can change the default splash on Android

Comment: I agree it's not meant for interaction; it would however feel better if I could see a progress bar or at least an activity indicator. I've been able to use that guide to create a static loading page, but was hoping for a bit more customization. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Perhaps you could apply the splash screen as background image to your landing page, then add a progress bar there. It won't take more than 1 or 2 sec for app launch, with same background image you could mimic the splash screen and add progress bar.